# Python - Getting all links from a div having a class

Tags: python

I am using BeautifulSoup to get all links of mobile phones from this url
http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-f-9-0-p2.php

My code for the following is :

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-f-9-0-p2.php"
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read();
soup = BeautifulSoup(text);

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'makers'});
for i in data:
    print "http://www.gsmarena.com/" + i.ul.li.a['href'];
```

But the returned list of urls is shorter than the expected output when i checked, this code outputs 3 values but the result should show much over 10 values

Comment: Looking at the source of the page, I see only 3 instances of `<div class="makers">`

Comment: And? How do you expect us to help you? Why do you expect this code to give you over 10 values?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are only three `<div>` elements in that page with a class of 'makers', this will print the first link from each div, so three in all.

This is likely closer to what you desire:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-f-9-0-p2.php"
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'makers'})
for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('a')
    for a in links:
        print "http://www.gsmarena.com/" + a['href']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Python 3, you can use Simon's answer with the following change:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = urlopen(base_url).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're only outputting one link per div, whereas it's clear from that site that there are multiple links, each inside its own li, and multiple lis per ul. You'll need to loop through all the lis.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/2.x/documentation.html:

> For instance, if you wanted to get only "a" Tags that had non-empty "href" attributes,
>     you would call `soup.fetch('a', {'href':re.compile('.+')})`. If you wanted to get all tags
>     that had an "width" attribute of 100, you would call `soup.fetch(attrs={'width':100})`.

Try this: `data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':re.compile('.+')});`

Should fetch all the divs with a class property present and not empty.