# Extract href value inside a div - beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print all the title of an anime from `https://gogoanime.pe/anime-movies.html?aph=&page=`with the following code from Bucky's tutorial:

```
def animmov(max_pages):
      page = 1
      while page <= max_pages:
            url = 'https://gogoanime.pe/anime-movies.html?aph=&page=' + str(page)
            source_code = requests.get(url)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            sopas = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html.parser")
            for link in sopas.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'img'}):
                  href = link.get('href')
                  print(href)
            page += 1
```

when i execute the code it prints the following `None`

I have tried to read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616928/python-getting-all-links-from-a-div-having-a-class) also but i can't follow through. How can i extract all the href link values inside the div.

Comment: `link.find("a").get("href")` should work first you need to find a tag and from it extract links

Comment: Hi @BhavyaParikh, so this is how extract a link tied inside a div. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the haref isn't part of the div-Tag, but an a-Tag within the div.
You have to use `href = link.find('a').get('href')`